# an orientable surface with infinite cyclic fundamental group must be annulus?

Tags: algebraic-topology

It is claimed in this accepted answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79929/how-to-rigorously-prove-that-simple-closed-curves-on-a-surface-are-primitive-clo that an orientable surface with infinite cyclic fundamental group must be an annulus. The user who gave the answer says that it follows from the classification of surfaces. I just do not know how to see this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, it does follows instantly from the classification of surfaces... Do you know the classification of surfaces?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: Now I see fundamental group of surface with genus greater than 0 has more than one generators. So it must be a sphere with holes. The fundamental group of a sphere with n holes is a free group with n-1 generators. Thus it has to be an annulus. It this right?

Comment: Sure, that works.